# Any way to achieve label format "Table X-X" in memoir WITHOUT using caption package?

Tags: floats, numbering, memoir

In standard book class, it is very easy to achieve the caption counter as the form of "Table 3-4" where "3" is the counter value of `\thechapter` and the "4" is the order of apperance of this particular table in the chapter. Simply use caption package:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}
```

`\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` may be the better approach to achieve that.

I wonder if there exists a way to define this type of label format in **memoir** *without using caption package*, since I am very satisfied with the additional float functions provided by memoir and do not want caption package to take over.

I have read the memoir documentation and did not find the answer. What is the internal mechanism inside the memoir that dominates the float counters?

----------------update------------------------

I found if you put `\mainmatter` before any `\chapter`, the command

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}
```

simply has no effect.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example. This will encourage answers and help people to help you effectively.

Comment: I've never used memoir, but section 10.6 of the manual looks relevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to load the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) for changing the numbering. It suffices to use

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}
```

with or without `caption`, even in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I actually tried before, it does not work. Now I find out it is the `\mainmatter` cause the problem. Please see the update of my question. Putting `\mainmatter` before `\chapter` make this ineffective.

Comment: Okay. Currently, the only simple way to solve that is to put `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}` after `\mainmatter`.